# Estou conectando o banco com PDO da maneira correta?

Tags: php, pdo

Há várias maneiras de se conectar com o banco de dados, mais optei por PDO. estou fazendo da maneira certa?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=experiments','root');

if ($pdo) {
    echo "Banco de dados conectado!";
}
elseif ($pdo) {
    echo "Banco de dados não conectado.";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Está no caminho, a sintaxe para conexão com a base de dados com pdo é dada da seguinte maneira:

```
$pdo = new PDO(dsn, user, password, options);
```

Sendo dsn a string de conexão com o banco(a sua está correta), user o usuário, password a senha e options que é um array contendo outras opções que é opcional.

Dou a sugestão que ao invés de utilizar a estrutura de controle if..else, utilize a estrutura de tratamento de exceções try..catch, pois ele tenta executar o código dentro do primeiro bloco e caso haja ocorrência de erro ou exceções automaticamente o código no bloco catch é executado. Da seguinte maneira:

```
try{

$pdo = new PDO(dsn, user, password, options);

}catch(PDOException $e){

exit("Erro na conexão com a base de dados");

}
```

Assim, caso ocorra erro será finalizada a execução do script e mostrada a mensagem "Erro na conexão com a base de dados", caso contrário não exibirá mensagem alguma.

Para mais detalhes do uso da estrutura de tratamento de exceções "try..catch..finally" ou outras, visite o manual do php.

Espero ter ajudado e Boa sorte ;)

Comment: ótima explicação, obrigado pelo esclarecimento.